# Capturing Data of a User Visiting my website

Tags: django, packet-capture, user-data

How can I capture data of someone visiting my website via a shortened link? I want to be able to capture the OS, IP, divide ID etc. Would capturing the user agent string be the best option? What are some other ways? In my case I'm building a website with DJAGNO.

Answer (score 0):

To get the IP, you can use the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` or `REMOTE_ADDR` headers from `request.META`
For instance:

```py
 FORWARDED_HEADER = "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"
 REMOTE_HEADER = "REMOTE_ADDR"

 headers = request.META

 ip_header = FORWARDED_HEADER if FORWARDED_HEADER in headers else REMOTE_HEADER

 ip_address = headers.get(ip_header)
```

For the user agent you can use the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` header:

```py
USER_AGENT_HEADER = "HTTP_USER_AGENT"
user_agent = request.META.get(USER_AGENT_HEADER)
```